# Automatically adding mailto: to a hyperlink field

Tags: database, ms-access, hyperlink, mailto

Within my database I have a field that store email addresses, but when these are selected outlook will not open until I manually change the hyperlink to an email address. Is there anyway to automatically do this because i have thousands of records.

Or even to automatically add the term "mailto:" to the start of each field, if this would work would this be an easier option?

Comment: I don't recommend adding "mailto:" to each address. The solution in the answer below is a much better approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with a little bit of VBA:

Put a hyperlink component on your form and change the field properties everytime a new dataset loads:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
  me.linkfield.caption="Click this to say hello to " & me![username]
  me.linkfield.hyperlinkadress="mailto:" & me![emailfield] & "?subject=" & me![greeting]
End Sub
```

Provided you have the fields username, emailfield and greetings in your table. The subject of course is optional